# Сброс буфера ввода ("читает лишнюю [пустую] строку")

Tags: c++, c, ввод

После ввода числа (например, возраста) считываю строку (например, имя-фамилию), но получаю в результате лишнюю пустую строку. Откуда она берется и как от нее избавиться?

Например,

```
struct Person
{
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int  age;
};

Person p;
cin >> p.age;
cin.getline(p.firstname,20);
cin.getline(p.lastname,20);
```

После этого в `p.firstname` оказывается пустая строка, а в `p.lastname` - введенное для `p.firstname`.

То же самое при попытке работать с функциями C

```
scanf("%d",&p.age);
fgets(p.firstname,10,stdin);
fgets(p.lastname,10,stdin);
```

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Добавите код или какое-то описание процесса?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Такая проблема чтения обычно вызвана тем, что после форматного чтения выполняется, например, чтение строки. Не вошедшие в форматные данные символы (обычно символ перехода на новую строку) при этом остаются в буфере ввода и считываются при следующем чтении как [пустая] строка.

Вот как может выглядеть такой *неверный* код на C:

```
fscanf(file,"%d",&intVar);
fgets(buf,buflen,file);
```

(само собой, то же относится и к вводу с клавиатуры - типа `scanf("%d",&intVar)`).

Или в C++:

```
inputStream >> intVar;
inputStream.getline(buf,buflen);
```

Могут быть и другие варианты.

Лечение (если не менять саму логику и функции чтения, что, конечно, тоже возможно) заключается в сбросе буфера ввода - игнорировании всех символов до конца строки между форматным вводом и вводом следующей строки.

В C++ это можно сделать при помощи следующего кода (который означает - игнорировать все символы до `'\n'` включительно):

```
inputStream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

В C можно явно считать и игнорировать все символы до конца строки:

```
while(fgetc(file) != '\n');
```

(Конечно же, имеет смысл также выполнять проверку на ошибку чтения - что считанный символ не равен `EOF`. При чтении с клавиатуры можно просто использовать `stdin` вместо `file`, можно - `getchar()`.)

Еще один вариант на C -

```
fscanf(file,"%*[^\n]");
fscanf(file,"%*c");
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще  всего:

```
cin >> p.age; cin.get();                                                           
cin.getline(p.firstname,20);                                                       
cin.getline(p.lastname,20);
```

Т.е. просто добавить *cin.get();* после форматного ввода. Этот вызов сожрёт нежелательный символ перевода строки в буфере ввода.

Comment: Не согласен - вы тем самым полагаетесь на то, что за числом *сразу* же идет `'\n'` - а это не обязательно. Соглашусь с тем, что нужна *проверка*, но не молча считывать один символ.