# getchar() C/C++

Tags: c

Совсем недавно погрузился в изучение языка C. Дошел до массивов данных и захотел применить некоторые знания на практике, но произошел коллапс. Суть программы такова: пользователь должен вводить 5-ти буквенное слово, далее в этом слове заменяется 1 буква. Какую именно букву заменить и на какую букву должен вводить тоже пользователь. В первом коде не срабатывает строка `swap = getchar()`,т.е ввод не происходит и программа продолжает свою работу.

```
int main(void)
{

char name[5];
printf("Enter a five-digit word: ");
scanf("%s", &name);

unsigned char swap_let;
printf("Enter the letter you want to change: ");
swap = getchar();

int swap_deg;
printf("Enter the number of the letter you want to change: ");
scanf("%d", &swap_deg);


switch(swap_deg)
{
    case 1:
        name[0] = swap_let;
        break;
    case 2:
        name[1] = swap_let;
        break;
    case 3:
        name[2] = swap_let;
        break;
    case 4:
        name[3] = swap_let;
        break;
}

printf("New name is: %s", name);


getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Но если я строку `swap = getchar()` закину в начало функции main, как в этом коде, то всё работает как надо(только в не правильном порядке).

```
int main(void)
{

unsigned char swap_let;
printf("Enter the letter you want to change: ");
swap = getchar();

char name[5];
printf("Enter a five-digit word: ");
scanf("%s", &name);



int swap_deg;
printf("Enter the number of the letter you want to change: ");
scanf("%d", &swap_deg);


switch(swap_deg)
{
    case 1:
        name[0] = swap_let;
        break;
    case 2:
        name[1] = swap_let;
        break;
    case 3:
        name[2] = swap_let;
        break;
    case 4:
        name[3] = swap_let;
        break;
}

printf("New name is: %s", name);


getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Помогите масленку с проблемой, возможно я как-то туплю, просидел около 1.5 часа и так и не разобрался.

Comment: Здесь принято давать код в виде текста, а не скриншотами... И так, для начала - пятибуквенное слово в массив из 5 символов не влезет - нужно место для нулевого символа.

Comment: Прошу прощения, учту в дальнейшем.

Comment: Учтите сейчас. Потому что набирать ваш код со скрина, чтоб разбираться, что и как у вас происходит - вряд ли кто-то станет...

Comment: учёл, еще раз извиняюсь.

Comment: В операторе *scanf("%s", &name);* симол *&* - лишний, так как имя массива и так уже является _указателем_ на первый элемент массива.

Comment: Весь оператор *switch* заменятся одной строкой *name[swap_deg-1] = swap_let*

Comment: В операторе печати добавьте символ перевода строки *printf("New name is: %s\n", name);*  и всё у Вас заработает! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что вы хотели:

```
int main(void)
{

    char name[6];
    printf("Enter a five-digit word: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    while(getchar() != '\n');

    printf("Enter the letter you want to change: ");
    char swap_let = getchar();

    int swap_deg;
    printf("Enter the number of the letter you want to change: ");
    scanf("%d", &swap_deg);

    name[swap_deg-1] = swap_let;

    printf("New name is: %s", name);

    getchar();
}
```

А почему сделано так, как сделано - читайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834447/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83).