# case игнорирует ввод строки

Tags: c++, switch, case

Почему в случае `ch = 3` в case игнорируется строка `gets_s(text, 150)`?
То есть при срабатывании этого `case` программа не дает возможности ввести `text`.

Текст заголовочного файла listcls.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class listcls
{
private:
typedef struct snd /* структура элемента хранения */
{
    char str[10]; /* элемент списка, массив символов */
    snd *n; /* указатель на элемент хранения */
} ListString;
snd* fs; //указатель на первый элемент списка
snd* ls; //указатель на последний элемент списка
int count; //счетчик элементов списка
void initList(char *text); //функция для создания списка

public:
listcls(char *text); //конструктор по созданию связного списка
~listcls(); //деструктор списка
void changeList(char *text); //метод для переопределения списка
int lenght(); //метод определения длины строки списка
char* initArray(); //метод для выделения динамического массива под список и внесение его в этот массив
void show(); //метод отображения строки списка на экран
int find(char *arr, char* tar); //метод, реализующий функцию, осуществляющую поиск заданной подстроки в строке списка
};
```

Текст listcls.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "listcls.h"
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;

void listcls::initList(char* text) {
    int i = 0, j = 0; //переменные-счетчики для указателей на элемент строки и на сами строки
    ListString* s = new ListString; //объявление массива указателей на структуру
    fs = s; //начинаем с первого символа
    while (text[i] != '\0') //пока не стартим конец стркои
    {
        s->str[j] = text[i]; //присвоение указателю значения
        i++;
        j++;
        if (i % 10 == 0) //конец элемента списка
        {
            j = 0;
            s->n = new ListString; //переход к новому элементу
            s = s->n;
        }
    }
    s->str[j] = '\0'; //указатель на конец строки
    s->n = nullptr;
    count = i; //запись в значение счетсчика количества элементов списка
}

listcls::listcls(char* text) {
    initList(text); //вызов метода создания списка
}

listcls::~listcls() {
    while (fs != NULL) {
        snd* n = fs->n;
        delete fs;
        fs = n;
    }
}

void listcls::changeList(char* text) {
    this->~listcls(); //удаление старого списка
    initList(text); //создание нового списка
}

int listcls::lenght() {
    return count; //отображение длины строки списка
}

char* listcls::initArray() {
    int n = lenght(); //размер массива - длина строки списка
    char* arr = new char[n + 1]; //выделение места для массива. "+ 1" - для нуль-терминатора
    int i = 0; //счетчик
    ListString* ns = fs; //начинаем с первого элемента
    while (ns != nullptr) //пока не последний узел списка
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (ns->str[j] == '\0') //пока не встретим конец строки
            {
                break; //досрочный выход из цикла при окончании строки
            } else {
                arr[i] = ns->str[i]; //заполнение массива символами из строки списка
                i++;
            }
        }
        ns = ns->n;
    }
    arr[i] = '\0'; //конец строки
    return arr; //возврат указателя на массив
}

void listcls::show() {
    ListString* ns = fs;
    while (ns != nullptr) // пока не последний узел
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // обход узла заполняем массив символами из узла
        {
            if (ns->str[i] == '\0') //пока не встретим конец строки
            {
                break; //досрочный выход из цикла при окончании строки
            } else {
                std::cout << ns->str[i]; //выводим символы из текущего элемента списка на экран
            }
        }
        ns = ns->n;
    }
}

int listcls::find(char* arr, char* tar) {
    int count1 = strlen(tar); //определение длины искомой строки
    int j = 0, check1 = 0, check2 = 0, res; /*j - счетчик для элементов искомой строки, check1 - проверка на свопадение элемента, 
                                            check2 - фиксация факта наличия подстроки в строке, res - вывод результата */
    arr = initArray(); //получение указателя на массив
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght(); i++)  //перебор исходной строки
    {
        j = 0;
        check1 = 0;
        while (j < count1) {
            if (tar[j] == arr[j + i]) //сравнение элементов строк
            {
                check1++; //счетчик успешных сравнений
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (check1 == count1) //если найдена подстрока
        {
            check2 = 1;
            res = i; //номер первого элемента подстроки в исходной строке
            break; //досрочный выход из цикла
        }
    }
    if (check2 == 0) //подстрока не найдена
    {
        res = -1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Файл main.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "listcls.h"
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char* text = new char[150];// переменная для ввода текста с консоли
    std::cout << "Введите текст: ";
    gets_s(text, 150);
    char* tar = new char[150];
    cout << "Введите искомую подстроку: ";
    gets_s(tar, 150);
    listcls list(text);
    std::cout << "Выберите действие:" << endl << "1 - Вывести список на экран" << endl
              << "2 - Показать длину списка" << endl << "3 - Переопределить список" << endl
              << "4 - Поиск подстроки" << endl << "5 - Выйти" << endl;
    int ch;
start:
    cin >> ch;
    if (ch == 3) {
        cout << "Введите новый текст: ";
        gets_s(text, 150);
        list.changeList(text);
    }
    switch (ch) {
        case 1:
            list.show();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << list.lenght() << endl;
            break;
            /*case 3: {
                cout << "Введите новый текст: ";
                gets_s(text, 150);
                list.changeList(text);
            }; break;*/
        case 4:
            cout << list.find(text, tar);
            break;
        case 5:
            list.~listcls();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Неверный ввод";
    }
    if (ch == 5) {
        delete[] text;
        return 0;
    }
    goto start;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто после

```
cin >> ch;
```

в буфере остается несчитанный `\n`. Вопрос многократно рассмотрен, см., например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834447/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83).

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!
Помогло добавление cin.get()

Comment: Ну, если вопрос решен - закрывайте, помечая ответ как принятый ("птица" слева).