# Отладчик неверно увидел символ

Tags: c++, visual-c++, отладка, visual-studio-2017, отладчик

Почему отладчик превращает 'e' в 'H'?
тексты программы: [case игнорирует ввод строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927560/case-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)
Спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вероятно это  юникод, а он отображает как ascci символ. И делает это, по тому что тип char, а не wchar_t, и соответственно туда влезает половина символа. Так-же как и ваша программа не будет вероятно корректно работать с широкими символами и результат будет непредсказуемый.

Comment: Так а что содержится в массиве `arr`? У вас в отладчике этого не видно - хвост строки на скриншоте срезан. Может у вас там и сидит это самое `H`? Рисовать нам красные стрелочки и рассказывать сказки на тему "я вводил вот это" не нужно - ваша программа работает не с тем, что вы вводили, а строит строку `arr` заново в некоей функции `initArray`. Учитывая общую адскую дикость кода (одни прямые вызовы деструкторов чего стоят), я не удивлюсь, если ваш `initArray` и запихал туда это `H`.

Comment: Разобрался, нашел ошибку в функции initAray(). И я не адский дикарь, а всего лишь учусь, всем спасибо:)

Comment: Приведите код в текстовом виде, пожалуйста

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927560/case-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8 - весь код вот здесь есть