# Очистить буфер ввода

Tags: c++, консоль

Пытаюсь написать кроссплатформенную функцию, аналог *system("pause");*

```
// Пауза перед закрытием
void PauseOnExit(int lang) {
    PrintVStr(14, lang);
    getchar();
    exit(0);
}
```

Все хорошо, но, если пользователь до этого что-то ввел - программа сразу закрывается, т.к. могли остаться непроанализированные символы в буфере ввода. И getchar этот прошлый ввод считывает. Вопос: как, собственно, очистить данный буфер? Решение должно быть кроссплатформенным.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834447/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83).

Comment: @Harry посмотрел. Увы, их код не пройдет. Т.к. в Linux и Windows закончить ввод можно ctr+клавиша

Comment: @Harry и никакого \n не будет

Comment: Переоткрыть стандартный ввод с опцией не блокировать. Перед getch ar сделать while read. Скушать буфер так сказать.

Comment: А вот еще стандартная функция есть на cin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
std::cin.clear();
```

Comment: А для чего cin.seekg(0,ios::end);

Comment: И что делает cin.clear();

Comment: Ни одного комментария...

Comment: `seekg` - переносит указатель для чтения потока в конец. `clear` - чистит на всякий случай влаги `eof` , `bad`, ...

Comment: спасибо!
_______________________________