# Считываение строк с помощью fgets

Tags: c, строки

Почему при выполнении моей программы игнорируется считывение полинома-B? (строка 3)
И как это можно исправить?

```
        case (SUM):
            puts("Enter polynom B: ");
            fgets(str_2, 255, stdin);

            rc = get_polynom(str_2, &lst_2);
            //print_list(lst_2);
            puts("");

            polynom_addiction(&lst, &lst_2, &res_list);
            print_list(res_list);


            break;

        case (DVD):
            break;
    }
```

Начало main:

```
int main()
{
    int rc = OK;
    char choice[255];
    char str[255];
    char str_2[255];
    node_t *lst = NULL;
    node_t *lst_2 = NULL;
    node_t *res_list = NULL;

    double a;

    puts("Enter polynom: ");
    fgets(str, 255, stdin);

    rc = get_polynom(str, &lst);

    print_list(lst);

    puts("CHOSE THE ACTION: val; ddx; sum; dvd");
    fgets(choice, 4, stdin);
```

Comment: Что считывается (и главное - как) перед этим? Есть у меня подозрение, что у вас [вот эта проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834447/%d0%a1%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83), но надо все же посмотреть, что у вас и как...

Comment: перед эти аналогичным образом считывается полином-А. Успешно считывается.

Comment: "Имя, сесга, имя!" (с) Приведите код, входные данные - чтоб можно было [воспроизвести вашу проблему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Входные данные могут быть любые. (Любая строка). Насколько я понимаю, проблема с fgets. (Код привел)

Comment: Еще скажите, что компилятор лагает... Проблема в программе, скорее всего в другом месте. Вобщем, без конкретного кода говорить не о чем.

Comment: Что значит "код привел"? Откуда выдран первый кусок кода? Какое он имеет отношение ко второму куску кода?

Comment: это начало main, если приглядитесь. какой код вам еще нужен? в программе 600 строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классическая проблема с `\n`, оставшимся сидеть во входном потоке. Чтение ACTION:

```
puts("CHOSE THE ACTION: val; ddx; sum; dvd");
fgets(choice, 4, stdin);
```

Пользователь введет, например, `sum\n`. Такой вызов `fgets` с лимитом в `4` считает только три символа `sum`, а `\n` останется сидеть во входном потоке. Именно этот `\n` и будет прочитан следующим `fgets`. Это будет внешне выглядеть так, как будто он игнорируется.

Правильное решение проблемы предполагает очистку оставшегося в потоке "хвоста"... но в вашем случае в расчете на "доброжелательного пользователя" можно просто предложить читать не `4`, а "до упора"

```
char choice[255];
...
puts("CHOSE THE ACTION: val; ddx; sum; dvd");
fgets(choice, sizeof choice, stdin);
choice[strcspn(choice, "\n")] = '\0';
```