# getline считывает строку из файла бесконечно

Tags: c++

В файле всего 3 строки:

```
nstructfile2
АБВ
4
```

Однако getline почему-то бесконечно читает файл и ничего не возвращает переменной spec[i].name даже на первой строке (которая в файле – вторая)

```
rd.open(fn + "2");
                            if (!rd) {
                                rd.close(); clr(red); printf("\nОшибка! Невзоможно открыть таблицу специальностей"); Sleep(3000); Cont();
                            }
                            rd >> automata;
                            if (strcmp(automata, "nstructfile2") != 0)
                            {
        rd.close(); clr(крас); printf("\nОшибка! Таблица специальностей поверждена"); clr();  Cont(); switch (uchar OMG = Cont()) { case '1':goto rewrite_file; case '2': op = '0'; }
                            }
                            else {
                                for (i = 0; !rd.eof(); i++)
                                {
                                    getline(rd, spec[i].name); rd >> spec[i].mes; n2++;
                                }
                                bar(3);
                                rd.close();
```

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак...

```
rd >> automata;
```

Считали словою В буфере - `"\n"`.

Цикл, обрекающий на как минимум одно лишнее чтение, потому что `eof` срабатывает только после попытки читать за концом файла... Откуда, ну откуда, какой препод вот такому учит?!

```
for (i = 0; !rd.eof(); i++)
{
```

Считали пустую строку из буфера - остаток `"\n"`

```
     getline(rd, spec[i].name);
```

Пытаемся читать в, вероятно, `int` (конечно, зачем этих отвечающих баловать, расписывать им все? и так догадаются, что я написал до этого места!) строку, которая не число

```
     rd >> spec[i].mes;
```

Файл переходит в состояние `fail` (в самом деле, не царское это дело - проверять, правильно ли все прочитано!) и все дальнейшие операции с ним просто возвращают ошибку. Но, как мы уже решили - проверять ошибки - унизительно для настоящего программиста...

Как исправить?

Прочесть [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834447/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83) и [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0), и, работая с файлами (и не только с ними), проверять, все ли в порядке...

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение! Да, spec[i].mes – не символьный тип. Я не стал это писать, поскольку не знал, где ошибка; а если отвечаещему нужны подробности, то он спросит и я всё что нужно распишу.
И проверки я не выполнял, конечно, по причине не знания