# При вводе строки программа уходит в бесконечный цикл

Tags: c++, строки, ввод, поток-ввода

Написал функцию для заполнения вектора объектами.

```
void fillBuyers(vector<CardBuyer>* buyers)
 {
try
{
    int countBuyers;
    cout << "Введите количество карт покупателей: " << endl;
    cin >> countBuyers;
    int number;
    string FIO;
    int discount;
    for (int i = 0; i < countBuyers; i++)
    {


        cout << "Введите ФИО: " << endl;
        cin >> FIO;
        cout << "Введите номер карты: " << endl;
        cin >> number;
        cout << "Введите скидку: " << endl;
        cin >> discount;
        CardBuyer buyer = CardBuyer::CardBuyer(number, FIO, discount);
        buyers->push_back(buyer);
    }
}
catch (exception & ex)
{
    cout << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

}
Проблема в том что при вводе в переменную `FIO`, строки например Petrov , все работает хорошо и программа переходит к следующей инструкции. А при вводе строки например Petrov Dmitrii Dmitrievich или если в этой строке будет точка то программа игнорирует следующие инструкции и входит в бесконечный цикл. При просмотре в дебаге в переменную записывается только Petrov , т.е. остальное срезается почему то. Вот код файла.

```
    #include "CardBuyer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
void fillBuyers(vector<CardBuyer>* buyers);
void searchBuyerWithDiscount(vector<CardBuyer>* buyers, int amount_of_discount);
int getCountBuyers(string path);
void readFromFile(string path, vector<CardBuyer>* buyers);
void writeInFile(string path, vector<CardBuyer>* buyers);
void showBuyers(vector<CardBuyer>* buyers);
int main()
{
    //SetConsoleCP(1251);//ввод в консоль русских символов
    //SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);//вывод из консоли   int counter;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string path;
    cout << "Введите путь для файла: ";
    cin >> path;
    vector<CardBuyer>* buyers = new vector<CardBuyer>();
    readFromFile(path, buyers);
    int counter;

    bool isExit = false;
    while (isExit == false)
    {
        cout << "0. Выход." << endl;
        cout << "1. Заполнить покупателей." << endl;
        cout << "2. Поиск карт со скидкой 10%." << endl;
        cout << "3. Вывести все карты." << endl;
        cout << "4. Записать в файл." << endl;
        cin >> counter;
        switch (counter)
        {
        case 0:
            isExit = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            fillBuyers(buyers);
            break;
        case 2:
            searchBuyerWithDiscount(buyers, 10);
            break;
        case 3:
            showBuyers(buyers);
            break;
        case 4:
            writeInFile(path, buyers);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Неверный ввод!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}

void fillBuyers(vector<CardBuyer>* buyers)
{
    try
    {
        int countBuyers;
        cout << "Введите количество карт покупателей: " << endl;
        cin >> countBuyers;
        int number;
        string FIO;
        int discount;
        for (int i = 0; i < countBuyers; i++)
        {


            cout << "Введите ФИО: " << endl;
            cin >> FIO;
            cout << "Введите номер карты: " << endl;
            cin >> number;
            cout << "Введите скидку: " << endl;
            cin >> discount;
            CardBuyer buyer = CardBuyer::CardBuyer(number, FIO, discount);
            buyers->push_back(buyer);
        }
    }
    catch (exception & ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }

}
void searchBuyerWithDiscount(vector<CardBuyer>* buyers, int amount_of_discount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buyers->size(); i++)
    {
        if ((*buyers)[i].getDiscount() == amount_of_discount)
            cout << "Номер карты: " << ends << (*buyers)[i].getCardNumber() << " ФИО: " << (*buyers)[i].getFullname() << " Скидка: " << (*buyers)[i].getDiscount() << endl;
    }
}
int getCountBuyers(string path)
{
    int count = 0;
    try
    {
        std::string line;
        std::ifstream file(path);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            while (std::getline(file, line))
            {
                if (line.find("*") != std::string::npos)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (exception & ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    return count;
}
void readFromFile(string path, vector<CardBuyer>* buyers)
{
    CardBuyer* temp = new CardBuyer[getCountBuyers(path)];
    try
    {
        string line;
        ifstream file(path);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < getCountBuyers(path); i++)
            {
                while (getline(file, line))
                    if (line.find("*") != string::npos) {
                        (*buyers).push_back(temp[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                    else if (line.find("Номер карты:") != string::npos) {
                        temp[i].setCardNumber(stoi(line.substr(_countof("Номер карты:") - 1, line.capacity())));
                    }
                    else if (line.find("ФИО:") != string::npos) {
                        temp[i].setFullname(line.substr(_countof("ФИО:") - 1, line.capacity()));
                    }
                    else if (line.find("Скидка:") != string::npos) {
                        temp[i].setDiscount(stoi(line.substr(_countof("Скидка:") - 1, line.capacity())));
                    }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (exception & ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }
}
void writeInFile(string path, vector<CardBuyer>* buyers)
{
    try
    {
        ofstream file;
        file.open(path, ios::app);
        for (int i = 0; i < buyers->size(); i++)
        {
            if (file.is_open())
            {

                file << "Номер карты:" << (*buyers)[i].getCardNumber() << endl;
                file << "ФИО:" << (*buyers)[i].getFullname() << endl;
                file << "Скидка:" << (*buyers)[i].getDiscount() << endl;
                file << "*" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Не удалось открыть файл!" << endl;
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (exception & ex)
    {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }
}

void showBuyers(vector<CardBuyer>* buyers)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buyers->size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Номер карты: " << ends << (*buyers)[i].getCardNumber() << " ФИО: " << (*buyers)[i].getFullname() << " Скидка: " << (*buyers)[i].getDiscount() << endl;
    }
}
```

Вхожу в цикл `while` и ввожу 1. Перехожу к созданию объектов. И при вводе в string начинается такая ситуация. В чем может быть проблема. За последнюю неделю столько программ делал, в которых вводил в string разные значения, и с пробелами, и с точками и все работало. Может как то влиять цикл `while` на этот ввод?
И вот на всякий файл с `CardBuyer.h`

```
    #pragma once
#include <string>
struct CardBuyer
{
public:
    CardBuyer();
    CardBuyer(int cardnumber, std::string fullname, int discount);
    int getCardNumber();
    std::string getFullname();
    int getDiscount();
    void setCardNumber(int number);
    void setFullname(std::string fullname);
    void setDiscount(int discount);
private:
    int cardnumber;
    std::string fullname;
    int discount;
};


//......................................................CardBuyer.cpp
    #include "CardBuyer.h"

CardBuyer::CardBuyer()
{
}

CardBuyer::CardBuyer(int cardnumber, std::string fullname, int discount)
{
    this->cardnumber = cardnumber;
    this->fullname = fullname;
    this->discount = discount;
}

int CardBuyer::getCardNumber()
{
    return this->cardnumber;
}

std::string CardBuyer::getFullname()
{
    return this->fullname;
}

int CardBuyer::getDiscount()
{
    return this->discount;
}

void CardBuyer::setCardNumber(int number)
{
    this->cardnumber = number;
}

void CardBuyer::setFullname(std::string fullname)
{
    this->fullname = fullname;
}

void CardBuyer::setDiscount(int discount)
{
    this->discount = discount;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в `cin>>FIO` оператор `>>`, как [**ему и положено**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2), читает **одно слово**. А потом, при попытке чтения числа на вход подается не число, поток переходит в состояние `fail` (которое вы не проверяете) и начинаются неприятности...

Читайте строками (`getline`). И еще - посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834447/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83), тут у вас тоже могут возникнуть проблемы.

Comment: Позволю себе добавить, можно не использовать getline, а прикрутить проверку на fail + clear & ignore ) Но некоторые считают что это такое себе )