# Не читает русский текст в блокноте .С++

Tags: c++, файлы, вывод

Нормально не выводятся русские слова, только текст на английском или цифры.
У меня дан файл (блокнот) в нем русский текст и мне нужно его прочитать.

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <Windows.h>
 using namespace std;
int main()
 {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

string path = "myFile.txt";
ifstream fin;
fin.open(path);

if (!fin.is_open())
{
    cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Файл открыт!" << endl;
    string str;

    while (!fin.eof()) {


        str = "";
        getline(fin, str);
        cout << str<<endl;

    }

}
fin.close();
```

}

Comment: Что значит "нормально"? Приведите пример выводи, и ваши ожидания

Comment: И еще у вас вот эта стандартная ошибка - `while (!fin.eof())`. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/834447/195342  Вы бы не могли сказать - откуда вы этот способ взяли? просто ужасно распространенная ошибка - настолько, что ощущение, что ее не то в какой-то книге привели, не то преподаватели, гм, неадекваты...

Comment: Есть видео на ютубе про то как читать файл. Код от туда.

Comment: У меня возникают типичные неразборчивые символы при русском вводе, если не написать это setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru"); Мне нужно чтобы с блокнота, все написанное на русском, отображалось.

Answer (score 0):

в общем и целом зависит от кодировки, в которой записан файл. Если windows-1251, попробуйте

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
SetConsoleCP(1251);
```

Comment: Я проделывал все это. Неразборчивые символы просто меняются на другие неразборчивые символы.

Comment: Разберитесь в какой кодировке текст в файле и в какой кодировке вывод в консоли. Проблема именно в этом

Comment: Все спасибо, помогли)