# Не считывает строку getline() C++

Tags: c++, строки, ввод, поток-ввода, getline

Решил сделать калькулятор (да, крайне странный), попрактиковаться в написании кода.
Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    char op;
    string answer;
    double x1 = 0, x2 = 0, Xr = 0;
    cout << "Введите два числа" << endl;;
    cout << "X[1] = "; cin >> x1;
    cout << "X[2] = "; cin >> x2;
    cout << "Выберите операцию(+,-,*,/,%): "; cin >> op;
    if (op == '+') {
        Xr = x1 + x2;
        cout << "Результат: " << Xr;
    }
    else if (op == '-') {
        cout << "Желаете получить отрицательное число? "; 
        cin >> answer;
        getline(cin, answer);

        if (answer == "Да" || answer == "да" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "yes" || answer == "y")
        {
            if (x1 < x2) {
                Xr = x1 - x2;
            }

            else if (x1 > x2) {
                Xr = x2 - x1;
            }
            else {
                Xr = x1 - x2;
            }
            cout << "Результат: " << Xr << endl;
        }

        else if (answer == "Нет" || answer == "нет" || answer == "No" || answer == "no" || answer == "n")
        {
            if (x1 < x2) {
                Xr = x2 - x1;
            }

            else if (x1 > x2) {
                Xr = x1 - x2;
            }

            else {
                Xr = x1 - x2;
            }
            cout << "Результат: " << Xr << endl;
        }
    }
        else if (op == '*') {
            Xr = x1 * x2;
            cout << "Результат: " << Xr;
    }
    else if (op == '/') {
        cout << "Делить меньшее на большее число(Без остатка)?  ";
        cin >> answer;
        getline(cin, answer);
        if (answer == "Да" || answer == "да" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "yes" || answer == "y") {
            if (x1 < x2) {
                Xr = x1 / x2;
            }
        }

        else if (answer == "Нет" || answer == "нет" || answer == "No" || answer == "no" || answer == "n") {
            if (x1 < x2) {
                Xr = x2 / x1;
            }
            cout << "Результат: " << Xr << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (op == '%') {
        cout << "Делить меньшее на большее число(С остатком)?  ";
        cin >> answer;
        getline(cin, answer);
        if (answer == "Да" || answer == "да" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "yes" || answer == "y") {
            if (x1 < x2) {
                Xr = fmod(x1, x2);
            }
            cout << "Результат: " << Xr << endl;
        }
        else if (answer == "Нет" || answer == "нет" || answer == "No" || answer == "no" || answer == "n") {
            if (x1 < x2) {
                Xr = fmod(x2, x1);
            }
            cout << "Результат: " << Xr << endl;
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что переменная answer не считывает ответ, а консоль выдаёт пустую строку и завершает работу. Пробовал читать документацию по работе с string и char, искал ответы на похожие проблемы, но так и не понял, как решить именно свою проблему. Поэтому пишу здесь, дабы хоть кто-нибудь помог дураку.

Comment: getline(cin, answer); <- вот так будет более верно. без cin >>

Answer (score 1):

Вы сначала инициализируете из потока ввода ваш `answer` до символа разделителя, оператором `cin >> answer;` потом пытаетесь читать в  тот же  `answer` всю оставшуюся строку( `getline(cin, answer`), а там что осталось, известно только тому, кто вводит...
Для вашего случая вам нужен ввод только одного слова, поэтому просто избавьтесь от лишней попытки читать еще и функцией `getline`.

В качестве замечания: старайтесь не повторять код каждый раз . Это  приводит к разбуханию вашего кода и отнимает у вас и у читателей(в том числе и компилятора/компановщика) лишней времени. И если еще попытаетесь избавляться от лишних условий, ваша программа будет более читабельной и качественней в плане скорости.
Кусок вашего кода может выглядеть (как минимум ) следующим образом:

```
cout << "Результат: ";
if (op == '+') {        
    Xr = x1 + x2;
}
else if (op == '-') {       
    cin >> answer;        
    Xr = abs(x1 - x2);
    cout << "Желаете получить отрицательное число? ";
    if (answer == "yes"/*...*/ )
        Xr *= -1; 
    //все остальные проверки сводятся на нет                    
}
//те же поправки  и для других случаев

//только после проверки всех условий выводим результат
cout << Xr;
```

Также не забывайте, что нельзя быть уверенным, что ввод всегда будет верным, и предусмотреть соответствующие сообщения о неверном вводе. И
не забывайте про оператора switch

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вы читаете 2 раза?

```
cin >> answer;
getline(cin, answer);
```

Закомментируйте строку с `getline()`, и все получится.

И вообще, смешивать `>>` и `getline` — [не есть здорово](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/834447/195342). Поэтому закомментируйте *именно* `getline`. Иначе все равно работать не будет, будете читать остающийся в буфере ввода `\n`...