# Как проверить строку на пустоту?

Tags: c++

Всем доброго времени суток! Мне нужно вводить имя книги и проверять в блоке try, если введена пустая строка или клавиша ENTER, то выводилось сообщение о неверном вводе. У меня получается так что блок catch почему то пропускается и не ловит ошибку. Заранее спасибо за ответы!

```
char* namebook = (char*)malloc(20);//буфер записи названи
puts("Введите название книги");
        try //проверка исключения
        {
            scanf("%s", namebook);
            int a = strlen(namebook);
            if (a == 0)
                throw(char*)"Вы ввели пустую строку";
        }
        catch (const char* exception)
        {
            puts(exception);
            throw(char*)"Вы ввели пустую строку";
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970617/how-can-i-check-if-char-variable-points-to-empty-string В первом же ответе показано решение вашей задачи

Comment: scanf не может вводить пустые строки

Comment: Я попытася вводить через cin и сделал проверку на конец строки (написал "\0") и все равно при нажатии ENTER не выводится сообщение об исключении

Comment: Покажите, как именно через `cin`.

Comment: std::cin >>namebook;
 if (namebook == "\0" or namebook == "\n")
       throw(char*)"Вы ввели пустую строку";

Comment: `>>` тоже не может в пустые строки. Правильно так: `std::string str; std::getline(std::cin, str);`. Дальше `str.empty()` проверяет на пустоту. Еще, сырые строки обычно не кидают как исключения (и что за странный каст?). Лучше `throw std::runtime_error("текст");`.

Comment: Еще, пишите в начале комметария `@username`, а то мы не получаем уведомления.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, как я понял, сначала инициализируем строку, затем вводим, проверяем на пустоту. Только вот у меня уже строка создана через `char* namebook = (char*)malloc(20);` и поэтому у меня сразу выводит сообщение об исключении, т.к строка изначально пуста и консоль не дает ввести ее

Comment: И ещё `if (namebook == "\0" or namebook == "\n")` не сработает, так как `namebook` - указатель, и вы сравниваете указатели, а не строки. Правильно: `if (strcmp(namebook,"\0") == 0 || strcmp(namebook,"\n") == 0)`, или так: `if (namebook[0] == '\0' || namebook[0] == '\n' && namebook[1] =='\0')`

Comment: @pumpkin А чем `std::string` не угодил?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat к сожалению по требованию преподавателя нужно именно так, как я описал выше. Есть варианты что делать если консоль не дает вводить и сразу бросает исключение?

Answer (score 0):

Как вам такой вариант?

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 20

char* namebook = (char*)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);//буфер записи названи
puts("Введите название книги");

try //проверка исключения
{
    fgets(namebook, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
    if (namebook[0]=='\0' || namebook[0]=='\n')
        throw "Вы ввели пустую строку";
 }
 catch (const char* exception)
 {
     puts(exception);
     throw "Вы ввели пустую строку";
 }
```

`fgets()` умеет работать с пустыми строками, к тому же защищает от переполнения буфера.

Comment: хороший вариант! но к сожалению так же не дает ввести название и сразу бросает исключение( не понимаю почему консоль не дает ввести данные

Comment: @pumpkin а вот это странно. У меня всё вводится, и исключение бросается правильно, как и должно быть. Вызов `fflush(stdin);` перед `fgets(...)` не забыли? Если нет, то может закралась ошибка в другой части вашего кода, а не в этом фрагменте...

Comment: честно говоря, я пишу сейчас код на онлайн компиляторе т.к у меня мак, а на visual studio 2022 для мак нету поддержки c++, поэтому возможно вы правы, что ошибка где то в остальном коде, в любом случае спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Автору вопроса: скорее всего, вы что-то вводите перед названием книги с использованием `>>` или `scanf` — см. вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/834447/195342 Автору ответа: приведение к `char*` строкового литерала — мягко говоря, неоднозначное решение. Чтоб не выразиться куда резче...

Comment: генерировать  исключение,  в  стиле "С" коде?  Для чего это смешивание языков?

Comment: @Harry "приведение к char* строкового литерала — мягко говоря, неоднозначное решение" - скорее бессмысленное, поправил)

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan C-код зачастую менее ресурсоёмкий, к тому же является законной частью языка C++. Так что почему нет?

Comment: @Harry "Автору вопроса: скорее всего, вы что-то вводите перед названием книги с использованием >> или scanf — см. вопрос ru.stackoverflow.com/q/834447/195342" Скорее всего так и есть. Вообще-то вызов `fflush(stdin)` был призван решить как раз эту проблему, однако похоже, что в случае `stdin` это не работает. Вот, что нашёл: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122550/fflushstdin-function-does-not-work

Comment: Я говорю о стиле, а не о языковых средствах. Если  полагаться  на  преимуществ "С" и на программиста, тогда нужно проверять errno, а не кидать исключение.  В данном   случаи стиль  "С " абсолютно никакого преимущество не дает по сравнению с проверкой, например, if (cin.peek() != '\n')
            cin >> namebook;
        else
            throw "  ???  ";

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` эту проблему не решает ничуть, это же не опустошение буфера...

Comment: P.S. Чтобы генерировать снова, достаточно сказать throw, но это ни к чему(приведет к необработанному исключению), так как исключение обрабатывается на месте.

Comment: @Harry я тут немного порылся - оказывается это далеко нетривиальная задача, стандартными средствами C++ очистить ввод от паразитных `'\n'` и при этом не блокировать поток. Поразительно просто! Я бы плюнул, и сделал это с помощью Win API...