Получение в переменную string текст с пробелами с++
Консольное приложение на c++, надо поместить в переменную string строку с пробелами, которую введёт пользователь. Попробовал множество методов, включая getline, всё четно, если кто знает альтернативные способы - поделитесь пожалуйста.
Код изначальный:
        cout << "You choise SW-043, input your text: ";
        string textUser;
        cin >> textUser;
        cout << encrypt_SW043(textUser);

Код с методом get:
        #include <string> // объявлена в другом файле
        ...
        cout << "You choise SW-043, input your text: ";
        string textUser;
        (cin >> textUser).get();
        cout << encrypt_SW043(textUser);   
        ... 

Если использую этот способ, то в переменную заносится только 1-е слово, дальше после пробела он не читает.
Код с методом getline:
        #include <string> // объявлена в другом файле
        ...
        cout << "You choise SW-043, input your text: ";
        string textUser;
        getline(cin, textUser);
        cout << encrypt_SW043(textUser); 
        ...

Этот метод, как и дургие getline он просто игнорирует, не записывая текст в переменную.

Да работает getline, работает... Готов спорить, что дело в этом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/834447/195342 — если бы вы дали полный код, закрыл бы как дубликат...

Да, оказывается проблема была в этом, ранее не сталкивался с этой статьёй, очень вам благодарен.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string input;

    std::cout << "Введите текст: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);  // Считывание строки с пробелами

    std::cout << "Вы ввели: " << input << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
